# In Elasticsearch how to delete a field in mapping I accidentally added?

Tags: elasticsearch

I accidentally added another field into mapping. All my documents do not have any  data in that field. Can I safely remove it from mapping?

Below is my mapping. I added an useless field called "query", and now I want to remove it.

Please help. I do not want to reindex all the data.

`{
    "twitter": {
        "mappings": {
            "tweet": {
                "properties": {
                    ......
                    "query": {
                        "properties": {
                            "abc": {
                                "properties": {
                                    "def": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    ......
                }
            }
        }
    }
}`

Comment: I don't think you can remove the field from the mapping without reindexing. But does having the field in the mapping hurt anything? I mean, I get that it's not aesthetically pleasing to have an extra field laying around (it would bother me too), but as a practical matter does it change anything? Here is a user-group post discussing the issue, thought it's a bit old: http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/Delete-Single-field-from-the-index-td4018900.html

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to delete a field from a mapping without re-indexing.  One can [add fields](http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/changing-mapping-with-zero-downtime/) without re-indexing. 
But deleting a field requires [deleting](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-delete-mapping.html) a mapping of a type which would result in removing all documents of that type and then you would have to put the updated mapping and re-index.